# What do I have to configure in order to get rid of too rigid tslint warnings in .vue files in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, vue-component, sublimetext, tslint

I use the *SublimeLinter-tslint* plugin for *Sublime Text 3* under *Windows 10* for linting the Typescript sections in my vue components. But in these I get a bunch of warnings that seem totally wrong to me, especially the first one that marks the `<script lang="ts">` opening tag itself - see the following screenshot regarding this issue:

[image]

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: I also opened an issue on the GitHub repository of [SublimeLiter-tslint](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-tslint/issues/42). To no avail so far. It seems that there currently is no solution and for developing Vue components there is no better editor than Visual Studio Code - I now switched to VSC. Who knows, in the end VSC might take over from Sublime Text.